# Cython and Exec()?

Tags: cython

If I made a python file named **hello.py** that has a script made like this.

```
msg = input("insert your message here: ")
script = '''
def say_something():
    print("{msg}")
'''

exec(script)
say_something()
```

And then I tried to use Cython

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("Hello.py")
)
```

It will show an error like this: `undeclared name not builtin: say_something`

I do understand why this happens but I'm not really an expert with python and C just yet. This is just an example, but it's similar to what I'm trying to do with one of my projects. Is there any way I could resolve this? I want to find a way to convert the script string into C as well.

I was trying to build an editable python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cython **compiles** the Python functions to a native binary that does what the CPython interpreter should do. `exec` is a function that execute arbitrary code at runtime (which is generally a very bad idea for speed, maintainability/readability and security). **Cython does not support `exec`** because it would mean that the could would be compiled at runtime. Thus, the code executed by `exec` cannot be a Cython code. However, the `exec` function can still be used to execute a pure-Python code. The error can be removed by turning off the [`Cython.Compiler.Options.error_on_unknown_names`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#Cython.Compiler.Options.error_on_unknown_names) in the setup script (just before calling `setup`) as pointed out by @DavidW. With this Cython will not complain when it does not find a function defined by `exec` (or similar methods). Please keep in mind that CPython can only be used in this case instead of Cython (which partially defeat the purpose of using Cython in the first place).

Comment: This isn't quite true. There's an [`error_on_unknown_names` compiler option](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#Cython.Compiler.Options.error_on_unknown_names) that can be turned off to bring back runtime lookup of unknown globals. I'm not convinced that what OP is trying to do is sensible, but their specific example can be made to work

Comment: @DavidW You are totally right! I did not know this flag. The example works by using CPython and Cython cannot be mixed with pure-Python code in the function executed by `exec` so Cython is not really useful here but I guess it solves the current OP problem. I updated the answer to clarify this point. Thank you.